# php getting data from an array of objects

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to use an php function that returns a variable $historicalData which is an array of objects.  The var_dump of the variable is:

```
  [0]=>
  object(Scheb\YahooFinanceApi\Results\HistoricalData)#40 (7) {
    ["date":"Scheb\YahooFinanceApi\Results\HistoricalData":private]=>
    object(DateTime)#22 (3) {
      ["date"]=>
      string(26) "2017-09-28 00:00:00.000000"
      ["timezone_type"]=>
      int(3)
      ["timezone"]=>
      string(3) "UTC"
    }
    ["open":"Scheb\YahooFinanceApi\Results\HistoricalData":private]=>
    float(153.889999)
    ["high":"Scheb\YahooFinanceApi\Results\HistoricalData":private]=>
    float(154.279999)
    ["low":"Scheb\YahooFinanceApi\Results\HistoricalData":private]=>
    float(152.699997)
    ["close":"Scheb\YahooFinanceApi\Results\HistoricalData":private]=>
    float(153.279999)
    ["adjClose":"Scheb\YahooFinanceApi\Results\HistoricalData":private]=>
    float(153.279999)
    ["volume":"Scheb\YahooFinanceApi\Results\HistoricalData":private]=>
    int(21958200)
  }
  [1]=>
  object(Scheb\YahooFinanceApi\Results\HistoricalData)#20 (7) {
    ["date":"Scheb\YahooFinanceApi\Results\HistoricalData":private]=>
    object(DateTime)#30 (3) {
      ["date"]=>
      string(26) "2017-09-29 00:00:00.000000"
      ["timezone_type"]=>
      int(3)
      ["timezone"]=>
      string(3) "UTC"
    }
    ["open":"Scheb\YahooFinanceApi\Results\HistoricalData":private]=>
    float(153.210007)
    ["high":"Scheb\YahooFinanceApi\Results\HistoricalData":private]=>
    float(154.130005)
    ["low":"Scheb\YahooFinanceApi\Results\HistoricalData":private]=>
    float(152)
    ["close":"Scheb\YahooFinanceApi\Results\HistoricalData":private]=>
    float(154.119995)
    ["adjClose":"Scheb\YahooFinanceApi\Results\HistoricalData":private]=>
    float(154.119995)
    ["volume":"Scheb\YahooFinanceApi\Results\HistoricalData":private]=>
    int(26299810)
  }
}
```

How do I extract data from this array of objects.  e.g. print the "date" & "close"?

**Update:**  I used the following code:
    DIR . '/vendor/autoload.php';

```
use Scheb\YahooFinanceApi\ApiClient;
use Scheb\YahooFinanceApi\ApiClientFactory;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

// Create a new client from the factory
$client = ApiClientFactory::createApiClient();

// Returns an array of Scheb\YahooFinanceApi\Results\HistoricalData
$historicalData = $client->getHistoricalData("AAPL", ApiClient::INTERVAL_1_DAY, new \DateTime("-3 days"), new \DateTime("today"));

echo $historicalData[0]['date'];

?>
```

And got the following error message:

PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type Scheb\YahooFinanceApi\Results\HistoricalData as array in stack.php on line 14

Comment: This is pretty much "How do I PHP?" so it suggests you need to familiarize yourself with the basics of the language. Start with [the section on arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: Assign a variable to the array $array = array(); and then call the value `$array['date'];`

Comment: I understand arrays.  It is when objects are put inside of an array that I get lost.

Answer (score 0):

To call a PHP Associative Array you will want to define a variable to said array.

For example;

`$MyArray = array('name' => 'Levi','Date' => '10/1/2017','Day' => 'Sunday');`

To get the name

`echo $MyArray['name'];`

or day

`echo $MyArray['Day'];`

In your case you would want to `echo $MyArray[0]['date'];` and `echo $MyArray[0]['close'];`

Comment: Thanks for you quick response.  However, I get an error message.  Updated the original question with the code and error message.

Answer (score 0):

I never figured out how to read an object inside an array.  But, I found this [code](https://ben.lobaugh.net/blog/567/php-recursively-convert-an-object-to-an-array) which will recursively convert objects inside an array into an array.  I managed to extract the data that way.